# Unable to get data from multiple kafka broker using different kafka servers with different topics and partitions in kafka c#

Tags: c#, .net, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have set up Zookeeper and kafka server on 2 different servers(34.196.151.95:9092,3.213.212.236:9092)
and followed below steps on 2 different server for testing and below URL - 
https://www.instaclustr.com/support/documentation/kafka/accessing-and-using-kafka/use-kafka-with-c/

- first server:  34.196.151.95:9092 for topic - test124 and patitions - 3

```
    cd E:\Kafka\kafka_2.12-2.3.0
    bin\windows\zookeeper-server-start.bat config/zookeeper.properties
    bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat config/server.properties
    bin\windows\kafka-topics.bat --create --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 3 --topic test124
```

- 2nd server:     3.213.212.236:9092  for topic - test123 and patitions - 2

```
    cd E:\Kafka\kafka_2.12-2.3.0
    bin\windows\zookeeper-server-start.bat config/zookeeper.properties
    bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat config/server.properties
    bin\windows\kafka-topics.bat --create --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 2 --topic test123
```

```
        var config = new ConsumerConfig
                {
                    BootstrapServers = "34.196.151.95:9092,3.213.212.236:9092",//.KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVER,
                    EnableAutoCommit = false,
                    GroupId = ConfigurationParameters.KAFKA_GROUP_ID,
                };
                GetAutoOffsetResetValue(ConfigurationParameters.KAFKA_AUTO_OFFSET_RESET, config);
                config.FetchMinBytes = ConfigurationParameters.KAFKA_FETCH_MIN_BYTES; 
                config.FetchWaitMaxMs = ConfigurationParameters.KAFKA_FETCH_WAIT_MAX_MILISECONDS;
                config.SocketTimeoutMs = ConfigurationParameters.KAFKA_FETCH_WAIT_MAX_MILISECONDS + 10000;
                config.SessionTimeoutMs = ConfigurationParameters.KAFKA_SESSION_TIMEOUT_MILISECONDS;
                config.MaxPollIntervalMs = ConfigurationParameters.KAFKA_MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MILISECONDS;

                consumerBuilder = new ConsumerBuilder<Ignore, string>(config).SetValueDeserializer(Deserializers.Utf8).Build();

                var topicPartition = GetTopicPartitionOffset();

                if (ConfigurationParameters.KAFKA_ASSIGN_OFFSET && !subscribeKafkaTopic)
                {
                    consumerBuilder.Assign(topicPartition);
                }
                else
                {
                    consumerBuilder.Subscribe(new string[] { "test123", "test124" });
    }
```

On both server Server.properties file have same configuration

```
       # Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
       # contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
       # this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
       # The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
       # (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
       # the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
       #
       #    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
       #
       # Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
       # distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
       # WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
       # See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
       # limitations under the License.

       # see kafka.server.KafkaConfig for additional details and defaults

       ############################# Server Basics #############################

       # The id of the broker. This must be set to a unique integer for each broker.
       broker.id=0

       ############################# Socket Server Settings #############################

       # The address the socket server listens on. It will get the value returned from 
       # java.net.InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName() if not configured.
       #   FORMAT:
       #     listeners = listener_name://host_name:port
       #   EXAMPLE:
       #     listeners = PLAINTEXT://your.host.name:9092
       #listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092

       # Hostname and port the broker will advertise to producers and consumers. If not set, 
       # it uses the value for "listeners" if configured.  Otherwise, it will use the value
       # returned from java.net.InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName().
       advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://34.196.151.95:9092

       # Maps listener names to security protocols, the default is for them to be the same. See the config documentation for more details
       #listener.security.protocol.map=PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,SSL:SSL,SASL_PLAINTEXT:SASL_PLAINTEXT,SASL_SSL:SASL_SSL

       # The number of threads that the server uses for receiving requests from the network and sending responses to the network
       num.network.threads=3

       # The number of threads that the server uses for processing requests, which may include disk I/O
       num.io.threads=8

       # The send buffer (SO_SNDBUF) used by the socket server
       socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400

       # The receive buffer (SO_RCVBUF) used by the socket server
       socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400

       # The maximum size of a request that the socket server will accept (protection against OOM)
       socket.request.max.bytes=104857600


       ############################# Log Basics #############################

       # A comma separated list of directories under which to store log files
       log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs

       # The default number of log partitions per topic. More partitions allow greater
       # parallelism for consumption, but this will also result in more files across
       # the brokers.
       num.partitions=1

       # The number of threads per data directory to be used for log recovery at startup and flushing at shutdown.
       # This value is recommended to be increased for installations with data dirs located in RAID array.
       num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1

       ############################# Internal Topic Settings  #############################
       # The replication factor for the group metadata internal topics "__consumer_offsets" and "__transaction_state"
       # For anything other than development testing, a value greater than 1 is recommended for to ensure availability such as 3.
       offsets.topic.replication.factor=1
       transaction.state.log.replication.factor=1
       transaction.state.log.min.isr=1

       ############################# Log Flush Policy #############################

       # Messages are immediately written to the filesystem but by default we only fsync() to sync
       # the OS cache lazily. The following configurations control the flush of data to disk.
       # There are a few important trade-offs here:
       #    1. Durability: Unflushed data may be lost if you are not using replication.
       #    2. Latency: Very large flush intervals may lead to latency spikes when the flush does occur as there will be a lot of data to
   flush.
       #    3. Throughput: The flush is generally the most expensive operation, and a small flush interval may lead to excessive seeks.
       # The settings below allow one to configure the flush policy to flush data after a period of time or
       # every N messages (or both). This can be done globally and overridden on a per-topic basis.

       # The number of messages to accept before forcing a flush of data to disk
       #log.flush.interval.messages=10000

       # The maximum amount of time a message can sit in a log before we force a flush
       #log.flush.interval.ms=1000

       ############################# Log Retention Policy #############################

       # The following configurations control the disposal of log segments. The policy can
       # be set to delete segments after a period of time, or after a given size has accumulated.
       # A segment will be deleted whenever *either* of these criteria are met. Deletion always happens
       # from the end of the log.

       # The minimum age of a log file to be eligible for deletion due to age
       log.retention.hours=168

       # A size-based retention policy for logs. Segments are pruned from the log unless the remaining
       # segments drop below log.retention.bytes. Functions independently of log.retention.hours.
       #log.retention.bytes=1073741824

       # The maximum size of a log segment file. When this size is reached a new log segment will be created.
       log.segment.bytes=1073741824

       # The interval at which log segments are checked to see if they can be deleted according
       # to the retention policies
       log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000

       ############################# Zookeeper #############################

       # Zookeeper connection string (see zookeeper docs for details).
       # This is a comma separated host:port pairs, each corresponding to a zk
       # server. e.g. "127.0.0.1:3000,127.0.0.1:3001,127.0.0.1:3002".
       # You can also append an optional chroot string to the urls to specify the
       # root directory for all kafka znodes.
       zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181

       # Timeout in ms for connecting to zookeeper
       zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000


       ############################# Group Coordinator Settings #############################

       # The following configuration specifies the time, in milliseconds, that the GroupCoordinator will delay the initial
   consumer rebalance.
       # The rebalance will be further delayed by the value of group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms as new members join the group, up to
   a maximum of max.poll.interval.ms.
       # The default value for this is 3 seconds.
       # We override this to 0 here as it makes for a better out-of-the-box experience for development and testing.
       # However, in production environments the default value of 3 seconds is more suitable as this will help to avoid unnecessary, and
   potentially expensive, rebalances during application startup.
       group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=0
```

I am able to consume data only from last configure server(3.213.212.236:9092) not from first server.

**Note - I am consuming data using c# window service**

Kindly suggest.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include your broker configuration please? Specifically, `advertised.listeners`?

Comment: Hi RobinMoffatt, please check server config file

Comment: Hi @RobinMoffatt, Please check and help.